# Referencing a enum defined in another proto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

In `A.proto`, I defined an enum called `Foo`. Then in  `B.proto`, I referenced this enum as:

```
message Bar {
    .pathofA.Foo foo = 1;
}
```

Notice that  `A.proto` does not have a go_proto_library declared. It's only in java. While `B.proto` has both go_proto_library and java_proto_library declared.

Now in `C.go`, I'm trying to build a `Bar` object, but I continuously got errors when trying to set the value for `Foo`. I could not import `A.proto` in `C.go`, as A does not have a go proto library. Would there be a way to reference/set value for `Foo` in C with only `B.proto` imported?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share to full .proto files and C.go?